# How do I make it a requirement for instances to have specific tags?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, tagging, amazon-iam

I am trying to create a policy that enforces tagging standards when launching new instances

I read about this in some of the AWS whitepapers and it appears that this is indeed possible now. However, the only example code I have found appears to be setting up these policies for volumes. I am unsure if I can accomplish this without having to use lambda (not an option for me right now). I attempted to create a policy with the code below. The "*" is simply stating that any value should be allowed in the mandatory fields (not sure if this is the correct way to specify that).

[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHM9Q.png)

I tried replacing the "RunInstances" with "CreateInstance" and "LaunchInstance" but that doesn't work either. I have already created this policy and tied it to a group. Then I added myself to that group to see if the policy would work when I tried to launch an instance. No joy. I am new to using JSON and would appreciate any helpful information. Note: JSON easier to read in picture.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCreateTaggedInstances",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:instance:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/Primary Owner": "*",
                    "aws:RequestTag/Project/Task": "*",
                    "aws:RequestTag/Environment (Dev/Test)": "*"
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "Primary Owner",
                        "Project/Task",
                        "Environment (Dev/Test)"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:instance:instance",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": "RunInstances"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, the condition that you are looking for is this.

```
"Condition": {
    "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
        "aws:TagKeys": [
            "Environment (Dev/Test)",
            "Primary Owner",
            "Project/Task"
        ]
     },
     "ForAnyValue:StringNotEquals": {
         "aws:RequestTag/Primary Owner": "*",
         "aws:RequestTag/Project/Task": "*",
         "aws:RequestTag/Environment (Dev/Test)": "*"
     }
 }
```

And then of course you need to select action and resource for which to apply this condition (required tagging).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did try this way and several other ways. It still isn't working. Think I will need to do more research.

Comment: I have tested it an it works. Just for testing purposes, try to change `action` to all ec2 actions and `resource` to `*`.

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/index.html#lang/en_us) Rules allow you to enforce this requirement by using an AWS Managed Rule called [required-tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/required-tags.html). Because it is a managed rule, you do not need to create a lamdba function.

Comment: Thank you for answering this. I actually already tried using AWS config as well to add a rule for required tags. But all that does is show which instances do not have the specified tags. It didn't actually restrict it.